# How can I mount Pv on one node and use that same PV for pods in another anode

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I have attached an EBS volume to one of the nodes in my cluster and I want that whatever pod are coming up, irrespective of the nodes they are scheduled onto, should use that EBS volume. is this possible?

My approach was to create a PV/PVC that mounts to that volume and then use that PVC in my pod, but I am not sure if it's mounting to same host that pod comes up in or a different host.

YAML for Storage Class

```
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-path
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
allowVolumeExpansion: true
reclaimPolicy: Delete
```

PV.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: redis-pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 200Mi
  storageClassName: local-path
  claimRef:
    namespace: redis
    name: data-redis-0
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt2/data/redis"
```

PVC.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: data-redis-0
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 200Mi
  storageClassName: local-path
```

no when i am trying to schedule a pod the storage is also getting mounted on the same node instead

Answer (score 2):

**you are using local path you can not do it.**

There is a different type of **AccessMount** ReadWriteMany, ReadWriteOnce, and ReadyWriteOnly with PVC.

> A PersistentVolumeClaim (PVC) is a request for storage by a user. It
> is similar to a Pod. Pods consume node resources and PVCs consume PV
> resources. Pods can request specific levels of resources (CPU and
> Memory). Claims can request specific size and access modes (e.g., they
> can be mounted ReadWriteOnce, ReadOnlyMany or ReadWriteMany, see
> AccessModes).

Read More at : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/

Yes you can mount the multiple PODs to a single **PVC** but in that case, you have to use the ReadWriteMany. Most people use the NFS or EFS for this type of use case.

EBS is **ReadWriteOnce**, so it won't be possible to use the **EBS** in your case. you have to either use NFS or EFS.

you can use **GlusterFs** in the back it will be provisioning **EBS volume**. **GlusterFS** support **ReadWriteMany** and it will be faster compared to **EFS** as it's block storage (SSD).

For ReadWiteMany you can also checkout : https://min.io/

Find access mode details here : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes

Comment: Hi, so its possible that lets say I have storage on node1 pvc1  and I want to schedule my pods at node 2, so there is no issue in that and whenever pods come up on node 2 and they will use that storage pvc1 on node.1 , or the pods would have to be on node 1 as well to use pvc1

Comment: if it will be on node 3 readwritemany there it will be able to use the that pvc with readwritemany same storage used by node one pod. it has not to be on that specific node,

Comment: ok so I am updating my question with the yaml files I used 

my issue is that the storage is always getting mounted at the node the pod is getting resurrected

Comment: you have used readwritemany ?  or it is just readwriteonce access mode ?

Comment: dont update question feel free to add new one with details and update the status of this question, you can mark it as resolve if resolve or answer your issue or else you can do upvote if found it helpful. in that case I have to update and remove whole answer.

Comment: ah sorry, i had already updated the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244709/discussion-between-avinav-gupta-and-harsh-manvar).

Answer (score 0):

> I have attached an EBS volume to one of the nodes in my cluster and I want that whatever pod are coming up, irrespective of the nodes they are scheduled onto, should use that EBS volume. is this possible?

No.  An EBS volume can only be attached to at most one EC2 instance, and correspondingly, one Kubernetes node.  In Kubernetes terminology, it only allows the ReadWriteOnce [access mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes).

It looks like the volume you're trying to create is the backing store for a Redis instance.  If the volume will only be attached to one pod at a time, then this isn't a problem on its own, but you need to let Kubernetes manage the volume for you.  Then the cluster will know to detach the EBS volume from the node it's currently on and reattach it to the node with the new pod.  Setting this up is a cluster-administration problem and not something you as a programmer can do, but it should be set up for you in environments like Amazon's EKS managed Kubernetes.

In this environment:

- Don't create a StorageClass; this is cluster-level configuration.
- Don't manually create a PersistentVolume; the cluster will create it for you.
- You should be able to use the default `storageClass:` in your PersistentVolumeClaim.
- You probably should use a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) to create the PersistentVolumeClaim for you.

So for example:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  volumeClaimTemplates: # automatically creates PersistentVolumeClaims
    - metadata:
        name: data-redis
      spec:
        accessModes: [ReadWriteOnce] # data won't be shared between pods
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 200Mi
        # default storageClassName:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: redis
          volumeMounts:
            - name: data-redis
              mountPath: /data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with ZebClient from https://www.zebware.com/
Just create a PVC with zebclient storage class and it could be used in any node or even machines outside the cluster.